# Jenkins mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

I try to configure docker + jenkins to build an android application but every time I get an error. Docker intalled with the help of
"Docker Toolbox" on Windows x64. Jenkins with the help of Kitmatick + DockerHub

> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue ?if it does

**This is my docker configs:**

**Client**:

```
Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm
```

**Server:** Docker Engine - Community

```
Engine:
  Version:      18.09.6
  API version:  1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.8
  Git commit:   481bc77
  Built:        Sat May  4 02:41:08 2019
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

**Jenkins configuration:**

> - Jenkins 2.164.3
> - Android sdk installed
> - JAVA_HOME default

**Full Response**

```
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Android build
using credential b8888ed9-b7f5-45c0-a0ed-ced60765fa29
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/3lolo/MyApplication2.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/3lolo/MyApplication2.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress https://github.com/3lolo/MyApplication2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision bfa10bbce1a819377b8de84bd3ee21845a23ce10 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bfa10bbce1a819377b8de84bd3ee21845a23ce10
Commit message: "fix aapt2"
 > git rev-list --no-walk bfa10bbce1a819377b8de84bd3ee21845a23ce10 # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[Android build] $ "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Android build/gradlew" build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-linux Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
8 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 7 up-to-date
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What happend when you run the same command in AndroidStudio terminal?

Comment: @Said Everything works. I run only build command. This project is a basic android studio template with one MainActivity. The Gradle command doesn't work on windows +jenkins and docker + Jenkins

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? We stumbled on the same issue. Not using Docker though. Windows based Jenkins installation. If I run it on the same machine manually from command line, it works.

Comment: @LukaBradeško No, but  Jenkins build works if I run the same project in windows workspace without docker.